# How to add messagebox in case of Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I want to improve whole code by adding MsgBox in case of:

Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

This Error is caused if clipboard is empty and I run the macro.
Any Advise?

```
Sub Test()
On Err.Number = 1004 GoTo ErrMsg
Dim Val As Variant
Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
Val = Range("A2").Value
Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
Call TextFromClipboard
Range("AY" & Val).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
ErrMsg:
MsgBox "Nothing to paste!", vbCritical, "Clipboard is empty!"
End Sub
```

[Orgin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521713/excel-vba-paste-text-from-clipboard-error-1004/60525778#60525778)

Comment: I always find it better to truly trap an error if it can be trapped, rather than relying on GoTo. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595258/how-to-check-if-clipboard-is-empty-of-text) for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always find it better to truly trap an error if it can be trapped, rather than relying on GoTo.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595258/how-to-check-if-clipboard-is-empty-of-text) you can create a function to see if the clipboard is empty.

```
Function clipboardEmpty() as Boolean
'requires reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

    Dim myDataObject As DataObject
    Set myDataObject = New DataObject

    myDataObject.GetFromClipboard

    clipboardEmpty = Not myDataObject.GetFormat(1) = True 

End Sub
```

You can then update your procedure to this:

```
If clipboardEmpty Then
    Msgbox "No Data to Paste!"
Else
   'Do Stuff
End If
```

Comment: I just add link for others who don't know how to enable reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610429/why-do-i-not-see-the-microsoft-forms-2-0-object-library)

Answer (score 2):

Use a select case in the error handler to handle the error number not in the goto statement.

You could probably remove the need all together for that particular error by [removing the selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and not using the clipboard.

```
Sub Test()
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    Dim Val As Variant
    Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
    Val = Range("A2").Value
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Call TextFromClipboard
    Range("AY" & Val).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet 3").Select
Exit Sub
ErrMsg:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 1004
        MsgBox "Nothing to paste!", vbCritical, "Clipboard is empty!"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't matter with this code, but I consider it good practice to put an `Exit Sub` just before the `ErrMsg` line.  You don't want to fall into the error handler unless there is truly an error.